# Who is credited for the syntax tree in synthetic linguistics

Tags: historical-linguistics, syntax-trees

I'd like to know who is the first person that introduced the tree of phrase structure in linguistics.

Comment: No, Reed & Kellogg.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Tree" has been a [thing in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) for some time. "Phrase structure" is a particular mathematical theory of syntax introduced by Chomsky. As far as I know the first phrase structure tree is on p. VI-205 (268) of "The logical structure of linguistic theory" (1955: [original version](http://alpha-leonis.lids.mit.edu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/chomsky_LSLT55.pdf)), where he explains the "Q-derivation" (VI-203a) with a diagram, recognizable as the derivation of some strings (words could be used by he used "c1 c2 c3 c4" etc). The same analysis is given in his dissertation *Transformational analysis*, a reduction to essentials of part of LSLT. It depends on whether you mean "both tree, and PS analysis". Tree diagramming is older.

Answer (score 6):

The French linguist Lucien Tesnière also used trees (called stemmas if I remember well). He has nothing to do with Chomsky, and is possibly older. I don't know if he inherited the idea of stemmas from somebody else. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucien_Tesni%C3%A8re#Stemmas